# how to create for QR Codes and implement to another pages to display

Tags: ios

want to create QR code reader based application. Using which library, I can create my application ? Note: I searched in google. Always I am getting zxing. I downloaded the zxing project … . But the problem is; I run the application. But it is reading only the Barcodes. There is no option to read QR code. Please tell me how to do this... Thanks in Advance. …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html), it reads both barcodes and QR code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 7 and higher you can use [AVCaptureMetadataOutput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureMetadataOutput/Reference/Reference.html) from standard `AVFoundation.framework`.

Below iOS 7 I've also recommend [ZBarSDK](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/)